# Bedeutung des Wortes die Wohlstandsverwahrlosung?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In Twitter ist der Hashstag #Wohlstandsverwahrlosung aufgetaucht. Beim Nachverfolgen des Hashtags #Wohlstandsverwahrlosung findet man verschiedene Themen, von Covid über Kinder bis zu Umweltprotesten. Warum so viele Bedeutungen?

Duden online Wörterbuch: "Leider ergab Ihre Suchanfrage keine Treffer." für dieses Wort.

Comment: Not saying that that’s a bad question, but did. You look up “Wohlstand” and “Verwahrlosung”?

Comment: I did not look up "Wohlstand" and "Verwahrlosung". I did discover the neglect of wealthy parents of affection but not material goods etc on the net. But could not see how this related to war in the Ukraine,  environmental protests ,etc. The wider cultural context of the word perplexed me, did not know a word for this idea in English.  One of the comments suggested "affluenza"  as a similar concept in English.

Comment: Richtig. Es ist immer ein guter erster Schritt, die Bestandteile einen zusammengesetzten Substantivs nachzuschlagen, aber in diesem Fall hätte es das Wort tatsächlich nicht vollständig erklärt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Begriff wurde in den 1990er Jahren von der Psychologin Ulrike Zöllner in ihrem Buch "Die armen Kinder der Reichen" geprägt. Ein ähnlicher englischer Begriff ist "affluenza".

Er beschreibt ursprünglich das Phänomen, dass Jugendliche, besonders Kinder reicher Eltern, in großem materiellem Wohlstand, aber mit wenig Zuwendung, Erziehung und gesetzten Grenzen aufwachsen. Sie sind es gewöhnt, dass ihre materiellen Wünsche erfüllt werden und dass sie selten um etwas kämpfen müssen. Beim Aufwachsen entwickeln sie sich zu materialistischen Egoisten oder Tyrannen, die wenig Empathie aufbringen, denen Konsum und Statussymbole sehr wichtig sind, und die sich schwer in einer sozialen Umgebung einfügen können.

Verwahrlosung bedeutet eigentlich, dass jemand sein Leben nicht mehr in den Griff bekommt und nicht mehr so "funktionieren" kann, wie es für sein Leben und seine sozialen Beziehungen nötig wäre, alles schleifen lässt, sich nicht mehr um sich selbst, seine Wohnung, seine Beziehungen etc. kümmert. Eigentlich kennt man das eher von hilflosen, oft armen oder psychisch eingeschränkten Personen. Hier wurde dieser Begriff - ursprünglich überraschend - auf Jugendliche angewandt, die aus Wohlstand und mangelnder Erziehung heraus gelernt hilflos sind.

Der Begriff hat sich aber inzwischen zu einem politischen Kampfbegriff verändert, mit sehr ausgeweiteter Bedeutung. Die damit gemeinten Menschen (nicht nur Jugendlichen) sollen sich demnach in westlichen Gesellschaften so sehr an Wohlstand und ein Leben ohne Herausforderungen und Hindernisse gewöhnt haben, dass sie nicht mehr in der Lage sind, die Sichtweisen anderer zu berücksichtigen, die Voraussetzungen des eigenen Wohlstandes zu erkennen, über ihre eigenen "dekadenten" "first world problems" hinaus zu denken usw.

In einer europäischen Gesellschaft kann das in weiterem Sinne fast jeder jedem vorwerfen. Die Klimaaktivistin sieht den SUV-Fahrer, der aus ihrer Sicht seine Wahrnehmung des Klimawandels seinem gewünschten Lebensstandard anpasst, als "wohlstandsverwahrlost". Der SUV-Fahrer wiederum sieht die Klimaaktivistin, die sich auf der Straße festklebt, als "wohlstandsverwahrlost", weil sie die ihr wichtigen Themen und ihren Protest absolut setzt und für wichtiger hält als die Gründe der anderen, die Straße zu benutzen.

Das Wort wird also benutzt, um Andersdenkende herabzusetzen, deren Verhalten oder Blick auf Probleme die sprechende Person selbst als dekadent, egoistisch, ignorant oder auf die Perspektive des verwöhnten Europäers beschränkt ansieht.

Comment: Gute Erklärung des Begriffs. Eine Anmerkung: Ich dachte, Verwahrlosung würde einfach bedeuten, dass sich nicht ausreichend um jemanden oder etwas gekümmert wird. Egal, ob Dinge oder Personen, und egal ob durch eine Person selbst oder einen Dritten. Also praktisch das Gegenteil von "gepflegt". Vgl. z.B. Formulierungen wie ["verwahrloste Spielplätze"](https://www.zeit.de/news/2015-05/28/gesellschaft-experte-viele-verwahrloste-spielplaetze-in-deutschland-28045605)

Answer (score 4):

Dieser Begriff wird als Synonym für Verwöhn-Verwahrlosung eingesetzt. Er setzt sich zusammen aus "Wohlstand" (wealth) und "Verwahrlosung" (neglegation).

Eine umfänglich passende Definition findest Du hier:
https://www.paradisi.de/leben/verwahrlosung/

In dem Zusammenhang mit den Umweltprotesten wird vermutlich dieser Teil der Definition gemeint sein:

> Wenn das Gegenteil (von Armut, also Wohlstand) der Fall ist, entsteht diese Art der Verwahrlosung durch zu niedrige Grenzen und eine antiautoritäre Erziehung. Eltern nehmen nicht genügend Einfluss auf die Förderung ihrer Kinder.

Kritiker werfen damit den protestierenden jungen Leuten vor, dass diese "schlecht erzogen" seien und sich deswegen so verhalten. Diese Vorwürfe sind Teil einer gesellschaftlichen Debatte und erfüllen oft den Tatbestand von Diskredition oder Verunglimpfung.